# How do I get WPF searchbox styling like GoogleChrome browser search?

Tags: wpf, xaml, search, google-chrome, styles

I am planning to have search functionality in WPF like it happens in Google Chrome browser. The sample is shown below

[image]

I have the backend code ready, but I want to have a TextBox like the one shown below - in which I can display the results also(like 0 of 0). 

Also I would like to have the arrow marks for next and prev. 
**How do I design such a TextBox in WPF in XAML? Please guide me regarding the same.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom control can be created using following code:

```
public class SearchTextBox : Control
{
    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(SearchTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public String SearchStatusText
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SearchStatusTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchStatusTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SearchStatusText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchStatusTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchStatusText", typeof(String), typeof(SearchTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    static SearchTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox)));
    }
}
```

Style in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                                 Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding SearchStatusText}"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2">
                            <Polyline Points="0,10 5,0 10,10"
                                      Stroke="Black"
                                      StrokeThickness="2" />
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="3">
                            <Polyline Points="0,0 5,10 10,0"
                                      Stroke="Black"
                                      StrokeThickness="2" />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will need to change it according to your needs. But this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Ready made solution for your requirement.You have to fiddle quite a few with the controltemplates of existing controls or you can build a custom control from scratch.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28VS.85%29.aspx